# Tensorflow unpooling operation using _max_pool_gradient

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

The unpooling operation as described e.g. in Zeiler 2014: https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2901, is equivalent to the gradient of the max pooling operation.

In tensorflow you could e.g. use gen_nn_ops._max_pool_gradient to do that, the function takes as input a parameter grad, in the docs it says:

```
grad: A `Tensor`. Must have the same type as `orig_input`.
        4-D.  Gradients w.r.t. the output of `max_pool`
```

I tried calculating the gradient of a max pooling operation using the compute_gradients() function of an optimizer, but those need a variable list with respect to which you can take the gradient, but in the case of a max pooling operation you would take the gradient with respect to the input to the pooling layer, so if the varlist argument to compute_gradients() is a tensor it wont work.

Can anybody please tell me how to get the gradients of the max_pool op, so that I can make _max_pool_gradient work?

Comment: The argument grad here should just be the input of the transposed pooling. If you use the operation as a transposed pooling, there is no notion of gradient

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot Thanks for your comment. What exactly do you mean be transposed pooling?I've read here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2169, that unpooling is given by the gradient of the max pooling operation. So I guess my question is how can I make the _max_pool_gradient operation work. What exactly do I need to supply for the argument grad?

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow supports this kind of operations, but they are a bit more low level. In particular there is [tf.gradients(...)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#gradients) which gives you access to computing partial derivatives. All you have to do is specify tensors which are supposed to be differentiated and which should be used for differentiation, so it efficiently produces `d ys / d xs`. Furthermore you provide `grad_ys` which is where they will be 'attached' (as originally it was designed to produce gradients using chain-rule, and TF is append-only thus you cannot connect gradients later on).